# Relation between "homotopical" and "representation-theoretic" categorifications

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, qa.quantum-algebra

This might be a bit of a soft question, and I apologize in advance for this. Here it is:

What is the relationship between the "homotopical" categorification (e.g. we consider every category as an $(\infty,1)$-category, or every sheaf as a discrete $\infty$-sheaf) with the "representation-theoretic" categorification (e.g. we replace polynomials with complexes, add quantum parameters etc.)?

Ideally (for me), the answer would look like some survey-type paper with an explanation of the second phenomenon in terms of the first one and several examples. But if there is some kind of folk wisdom regarding this, I would also be delighted.

The [nlab entry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/categorification+in+representation+theory) on this, although clearly written with something like this in mind, looks like a stub, and I can't extract the general picture from it.

Comment: One motivation for Khovanov-type categorification is to get nontrivial 3+1 TQFTs. The idea is that 2+1 TQFTs (more specifically, 3-2-1) are essentially the same as modular tensor categories (MTCs). This is the Reshetikhin-Turaev construction. If you try to go one dimension up you get invertible 3+1 TQFTs, which are not so interesting. However, the idea is that replacing an MTC with a 2-category gives enough room to get a non-invertible 3+1 TQFT by repeating Reshetikhin-Turaev.

Comment: This is still a pretty imprecise explanation (hence why it's a comment not an answer) but maybe it's more in the direction you're looking for?

Comment: The short version is that to pass to higher-dimensional TQFT you need more and more algebraic data in your input: from Froenius algebras  for 1+1 dimensions to MTCs (special 2-categories with a single object) for 2+1 to more general types of 2-category for 3+1.

Comment: @CalvinMcPhail-Snyder Yes, this seems like a great starting point! Are there some introductory references for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any particular survey that addresses this: I've learned it as folk wisdom. I think it's sometimes called the "ladder construction".

Comment: Some parts of this program are just being realized mathematically, as in https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.04616 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.05640, but those are definitely not survey papers.